# fortran variables in modules give unexpected value

Tags: module, fortran, mpi, fortran90

The program is used in the context of MPI.It's a MPI implementation of fortran.
I declare an array within a module.like

```
module var
 real,save ::arr(8)
end module
```

Then use a subroutine like `init` to initialize the array arr.
In the main program unit,first call `init` to initialize the array arr.And then call another
subroutine like `algo` to do some computations.At the beginning of subroutine `algo`,the value of arr is correct.During the process of computation,the value of arr changed weirdly on some processors though there is no code changing the value of arr while on the other processors the value is correct.
I check the code and I am pretty sure no code change the value of arr during computation.
By the way,numbers of variables declared within the module var are numerous.

Comment: I've had a few situations before where I wrote past the end of an array and changed the value of other variables. Could that be happening here?

Comment: actually the variable got its correct value when entering the subroutine which means the initialization is correct.And the process of the subroutine `algo` involves changing other variables which have no connection with `arr`.The value I need is within the range of the variable `arr`.

Comment: Could you give a MWE of your problem?

Comment: @witrus Nothing you said is actually evidence that you didn't overwrite your variable. It is probably unlikely, but depending on how your variables live on the stack, it is still possible.

Comment: Post some working example and enable bounds checking and other available error checks of your example. @patrickvacek may be right.

Comment: @MBR,what do u mean by MWE.I do not understand what MWE is

Comment: @VladimirF,it is a large program and difficult to give out the source code.Is is a possibility that different variables in a module share the same memory address?

Comment: @witrus **MWE** stands for _Minimum Working Example_; you should provide a piece of code that is fully running and which reproduces your error to help the others to pin down your problem.

Comment: If your compiler can do that, tell it to compile with array bound checks. At least it should eliminate one possible reason for failure. And try to track all places in your program where your array is modified (you could put some "print" around them to see what happens at run time). Alternately, debuggers have often a way to do some task upon variable modification, you could try that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you who give suggestions.The error is due to the access of array element out 
of boundary.In my program there is a line of code accessing the index 0 element in array like
`arr(0)=...` which is beyond the range of fortran array.And this code leads to the value of another variable in the module to be changed which is quite unexpected to me.`arr(0)=..` leads to the change of another variable like `parm` defined in the module.

Comment: Well, if your brain has ever been addled by exposure to C or one of its relatives you can think of `a(0)` as *the variable at the memory location(s) preceding the location of a(1)* and conclude that that is where `parm` is sitting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MPI, you must also broadcast the variable to all processors if the initialization is being done only on one processor